# Importing WGS84 points into project CRS OSGB36 broken, showing black screen

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, attribute-table, csv, wgs84

I am relatively new to all things GIS.

I am trying to import CSV points collected in WGS84 format eg. LAT 55.93887932 LONG -4.50803484, into a project with CRS set to OSGB36 (EPSG: 27700).

This is because I am dealing with multiple sources of data from Government repositories and most of the data is stored in OSGB format so I thought I should set the project CRS to that.

But one layer of data has been collected in WGS84 format like the example.

I imported as CSV, and made sure to select the layer CRS to WGS84 (EPSG:7664) when importing, so thought it wouldn't be an issue and the program would just convert it to OSGB36.

However, none of the points appear on the map I'm creating, and when I select "zoom to layer" all my other layers become invisible (screen shows black) with the imported points floating on the black. The only way I can get the black to go away is deleting the layer.[image]

How do I fix this? Image attached

Comment: I googled it and got this: "Latitude is the Y axis, longitude is the X axis" so followed that when importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your CSV layer to EPSG:7664, you need to use [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.io/4326) (WGS84).

[EPSG:7664](https://epsg.io/7664) is not an appropriate CRS to use as your coordinates are geographic lon, lat (degrees). EPSG:7764 is not a geographic CRS and its units are not degrees.

I just added your example point as a delimited text layer to QGIS, set the layer CRS to EPSG:4326 (WGS84) and the project CRS to EPSG:27700. I added a basemap (OSM) and zoomed into the point which shows up just northwest of Glasgow in a quarry.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much! You're a legend. Would you mind expanding on why it's not an appropriate CRS/ linking to an explanation?

Comment: See edit for why its not appropriate.